# Obtain a variable from inside a class into a new script python

Tags: python, tkinter

Simple question, i don't have major experience in Python and this is just a challenge to help with my experience. I have a variable called 'resolution' that is inside a method inside a class. Here you can see the code:

```
class LauncherWindow(Frame):
def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.master.title('RPG-game')
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    self.run_gui()

def run_gui(self):
    resolutions = ('1920 x 1080',
                   '1920 x 1080',
                   '1600 x 900',
                   '1280 x 720',
                   '640 x 800')

    resolution = StringVar()
    resolution.set(resolutions[0])

    auto_image = Image.open('resources/launcher/launcher.png')
    render_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(auto_image)
    image_print = Label(self, image=render_image)
    image_print.image = render_image
    image_print.pack()

    play_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Play!', command=lambda: start_game())
    play_button.pack(side=BOTTOM, pady=10)

    main_frame = Frame(self, bg='#D6D7D7')

    select_resolution = ttk.Label(main_frame, text='Select resolution:', background='#D6D7D7')
    select_resolution.pack(side=LEFT)

    select_resolution_entry = ttk.OptionMenu(main_frame, resolution, *resolutions)
    select_resolution_entry.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10)

    windowed_mode = ttk.Label(main_frame, text='Windowed:', background='#D6D7D7')
    windowed_mode.pack(side=LEFT)

    windowed_checkbutton = Checkbutton(main_frame, background='#D6D7D7')
    windowed_checkbutton.pack(side=LEFT, padx=2)

    main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, padx=50, side=BOTTOM, pady=20)

    def start_game():
        print('starting game')
        for i in resolutions:
            if resolution.get() == i:
                print(resolution.get())
```

My assumption is that i would need to make a global variable to which i can import to new script, can i have any guidance for this matter?

if i do need to create a variable outside of the class, how do i access that variable in a method inside the class?

Example: I have a script called MainGame.py, i want to be able to use the resolution variable in this script.

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect in the question.

Answer (score 0):

well you set the resolution variable when running the method run_gui(), so i assuume you have a instance of the class LauncherWindow, so you can always save the variable as a member of the class and then access it like this:

```
class LauncherWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.title('RPG-game')
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.resolution = "1920 x 1080"
        self.run_gui()
```

and at MainGame.py

```
x = LauncherWindow()
print x.resolution
```

that way you can change it in methods like run_gui()

if you do want to just save it as a static variable ( not related to an instance of the LauncherWindow class) you can save it this

```
class LauncherWindow(Frame):
    RESOLUTION = "1920 x 1080"

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.title('RPG-game')
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.run_gui()
```

in this way you will only have one "resolution" it will remain static and if someone changes it, it will change for all instances of LauncherWindow

this time you can access it like

```
print LauncherWindow.RESOLUTION
```

no need to create an instance here

Comment: Thanks :) I had some sort of understanding about the instance but i went the wrong approach to accessing it!